# History of notation of sets: Why $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ for integers and rationals, but $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ for reals and naturals?

Tags: math-history

Why do we denote set of integers as $\mathbb Z$ and set of rationals as $\mathbb Q$, although we use $\mathbb R$ for real, $\mathbb N$ for natural numbers, etc. What's the reason or history behind it?

Comment: Start here: http://jeff560.tripod.com/nth.html

Comment: $\mathbf Z$ comes from *Zahlen*,  the german word for ‘numbers’. As to $\mathbf Q$, it is the first letter of *Quotient*.

Comment: This is a good question for the [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the conjunctions "but" and "although"? Do you see some kind of tension between $\mathbb Z,\mathbb Q$ on the one hand and $\mathbb R,\mathbb N$ on the other? Can you tell us what it is? What letters would you have chosen to denote those four sets?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ match the first letters of the English words; $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ don't.

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments above.*

---

The notation $\mathbb{Z}$ for the set of integers comes from the German word *Zahlen* for *numbers*.

The notation $\mathbb{Q}$ for the set of rational numbers was chosen to indicate that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of *quotients* of integers.

You might find [this site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/nth.html) informative on the history of these notations.